# Need '/n' but getting parsed as new line- Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse, data-transform

There are some escape characters in the source files(JSON in Azure Blob) – /” and /n. When I am transforming the files through copy activity or dataflow, these characters are getting parsed and I am getting just the “ and new line in the sink file. While I need the /” to be parsed to “ I need the /n to come as a string only and not new line. Is there some way I can achieve this? The quote character and escape character options in Delimited text dataset is not helping as I need the quote character setting to be configured to no quote character.

This is how a sample JSON looks-
"Value" : "<xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \n some data \n some data>"

In copy-activity or dataflow the source looks like this in preview mode-

xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"<br/some data
some data>

I need something like this-
<xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" \n some data \n some data>

So for my scenario, the \n needs to preserved and not get parsed as new line. I have tried adding \\n in the source and that worked but sadly changing at the source side is not possible. Can I do something like this in Synapse itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider dataflows derived column transformations to read all data as single column and replace `\n` as `\\n` first in source file. Once you update source file then use copy activity.

Or

You can consider have a code deployed in Azure functions which can update source file to replace `\n` as `\\n` first and then use copy activity to copy file.

Comment: Can I get some more details as to how the replace(data manipulation) is possible in dataflows derived column activity?